# Google Plus and OpenSocial

Tags: opensocial, google-plus

It [appears](http://www.developerfusion.com/news/122215/google-reveals-a-few-secrets-powering-google/) Google Plus is mainly written using Java on the server side. So I wonder if it will be compatible with the existing [OpenSocial](http://code.google.com/apis/opensocial/) APIs Google has created with MySpace.
It could easily be done using [Apache Shindig](http://shindig.apache.org/), the reference OpenSocial implementation for Java.

Does anyone has information about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it runs on open social.

Watch the requests in your browser and you will see something like this:

```
https://r3101-dot-latest-dot-project-slingshot-gp.appspot.com/
?loadFrom=ES
&jsh=r;gc/[OBSCURED]#id=gameIframe
&parent=https://upt14k1i2veesusrda9nfotcrbp9d7p5-a-oz-opensocial.googleusercontent.com
&rpctoken= [OBSCURED]
&_methods=_ready,_close,_open,_resizeMe
```

the domain **...opensocial.googleusercontent.com** seems to make it pretty obvious whats going on here, no?

Comment: Ok, interesting. I looked for it, and it's true. I found it in the requests launched by Plus. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Google+ doesn't have an API yet. As they wrote their own APIs for Google Buzz, not being OpenSocial enabled this time might tell us that they have abandoned OpenSocial...